# How to do root test on this power series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

I have this power series,

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$

I apply the root test as such,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \left(  \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac{x}{\ln(n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}
$$

And Wolfram tells me when,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} = 1$$
Firstly how do I prove that's true?
Secondly How I interpet this?
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \left(  \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac{x}{1}= x$$

Comment: In the last line, you're equating two very different things: the sum of the series, and the limit of the root of the $n$th term in that series.

Comment: What @MatthewLeingang said.  The equation $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \left(  \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x^n}{\ln x}\right|^{1/n} = |x|$$To show that $(\ln n)^{1/n} \to 1$, start with the fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n} = 0$$ to show that $ 1 < \ln n < n$ eventually for all $n$. Then take $n$th roots and limits.

The [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) says that the series converges absolutely if this limit is less than $1$, and diverges if the limit is greater than $1$.

So now you know the series converges absolutely if $|x|<1$, and diverges if $|x|>1$. That is, the radius of convergence of this power series is $1$.

Comment: Okay, so it convergence for every $|x|<1$

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly how do I prove that's true? $ \lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} = 1 $

You shoul try the prove with the ln and exp laws.

How I would prove it:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} &= 1\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \sqrt[n]{e^{\ln(\ln(n))}} &= 1\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} (e^{\ln(\ln(n))})^{\frac{1}{n}} &= 1\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} e^{\ln(\ln(n)) \cdot \frac{1}{n}} &= 1\\
e^{\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \ln(\ln(n)) \cdot \frac{1}{n}} &= 1 \quad\mid\quad \ln(~~)\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \ln(\ln(n)) \cdot \frac{1}{n} &= 0\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{n} &= 0 \quad\mid\quad \text{rule of l'hospital}\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}n} ~ \ln(\ln(n))}{\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}n} ~ n} &= 0\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}n} ~ \ln(\ln(n))}{1} &= 0\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}n} ~ \ln(\ln(n)) &= 0\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln(n)} &= 0\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{\ln(n^{n})} &= 0\\
\frac{1}{\ln(\infty^{\infty})} = \frac{1}{\infty} = \lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{n} &= 0\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}}\frac{1}{n} &= 0\\
0 &= 0 \qquad \square
\end{align*}
$$

> Secondly How I interpet this? $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \left(\frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac{x}{1}= x $

These seems to be "fun with identities"...

The equation just shows, as far as I can see, that you can use both to solve it.

Comment: It is much easier to use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence. After you have found, by whatever method, that the radius of convergence is 1, you probably wish to determine if the series converges for $x=\pm 1$. At $x=-1$,use the alternating series test. At $x=1,$ use Raabe's test.